# ¿Cómo editar los comentarios que apararecen por ejemplo al crear clases en Intellij Idea? (Personalizar)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

cuando se crea una nueva clase se crea con contenido de comentarios arriba ejemplo:

```
/**
 * Created by rwn on 5/3/2017.
 */
```

como puedo configurar mi ide idea intellij para que genere automaticamente asi:

```
/**
 * @author rwn
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede acceder a las plantillas desde el menu:

<kbd>Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor</kbd> -> <kbd>File and Code Templates</kbd>

*para acceder al menu **preferences** suele estar en muchas versiones bajo el boton **IntelliJ IDEA** arriba a la izquierda para macOS*

Ahora depende de su version puede encontrar algo similar a esto

**Tab** | *Files* | *Includes* | *Code* | *Other*

---

*imagen para guia.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

existen variables predefinidas que al expandirse retornan valores las cuales puede usar para lo que usted busque, [aqui](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html) puede mirarlas.

---

por ejemplo :

`${USER}` - Al expandirse mostrara el nombre de inicio de sesión del usuario actual.

---

**Notas:** En algunos OS segun la documentacion puede estar en -> **File | Settings para Windows y Linux** :

<kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor</kbd> -> <kbd>File and Code Templates</kbd>

Y el resto similar a lo mencionado anteriormente.

---

si esta teniendo problemas para abrir o encontrar el menu **editor** quizas pueda hacer uso de lo siguiente, para lanzarlo:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>